# Basic explanation of Context in android

Tags: java, android, syntax

"If you can't explain it to a six year old, you don't understand it yourself." 
— Albert Einstein

After reading about a context on the android developer web site and various other places on the web I am still a bit fuzzy. In this line of code I am a bit confused what the parameter really means. I am not ashamed to get a 6 year old answer....

TextView textView = new TextView(getBaseContext());

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to explain context in Android to friend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433457/trying-to-explain-context-in-android-to-friend)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Sea for a fish,
- sky for a bird,
- nest for a birdie,
- a rabbit hole for a rabbit,
- the space where a javax.swing.JComponent is drawn.

A context, is a way to describe the ether/environment an entity lives in and how to access other stuff living in this environment, interact with it.

:)
First attempt of poetic answer for stack over flow ;)

At least, a 6 years old child would get the first four analogies.

More pragmatically, we can find different way to conceptualize what a context is, but it remains what the methods of this interface can offer as a set of services.

Answer (score 1):

Context is a bridge through which the vehicles passes from one place to another place...
Here the places are the components of an application such as Activity, Receiver, Service etc...
You can say its a medium of sharing information...

Answer (score 0):

"Context" loosely means the environment in which the object lives.  It provides access to other things within that environment.  Activities and Services both inherit the Context class, so you can always access components related to where they are running.